# glfw initialization succseeds, but stdio.h functions don't work

Tags: c++, stdout, glfw

I want to write an raycaster and in the current stage I want to implement textures.
However I noticed the function fopen seemed not to detect an existing file (even using the absolute path). Then I wantet to try printing something and that failed too. Strangely there are no linking errors, nor runtime crashes. I have stripped my code down to the initialization of glfw and one test printf call. (It still doesn't work)

I compile/link with g++ on windows with the following flags "-lgdi32 -lgdiplus -mwindows -lopengl32 -lkernel3 -L E:\Code\CPP\PrimitiveRacing\libs\glfw -l:libglfw3.a". Since I use C++ i moved the include of both glfw, and stdio.h into an extern "C" scope. My search for user with the same problem had no success, I found this question [Can't print OpenGL buffer to console in a GLEW application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369296/cant-print-opengl-buffer-to-console-in-a-glew-application) but adding fflush didn't help. All other questions I got are about linking problems or the application not responding which doesn't happen to me.

```
int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    
    printf("a"); // isn't printing
    fflush(stdout); // isn't helping

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(window_width, window_height, TITLE, NULL, NULL);
    
    if (!window)
    ...
```

Comment: `-mwindows` disables the console window and any output, remove it.